# format htmlhelper date field to dd/mm/yyyyy

Tags: html-helper, date-format

I need to encode an htmlhelper date to "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}. Current result in dd/mm/yyyy hr:mins:sec

```
<%= Html.Encode(Model.myTable.DOB)%>
```

I also need to enforce a datepicker to format "dd/mm/yyyy".

```
<%= Html.DatePicker("DOB", "/Content/Images/calendar.png", Model.ApplicantStatus.DOB)%>
```

Answer (score 0):

to mask date on Html.Encode, use:

```
<%= String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", Model.myTable.DOB%>
```

to format dd/mm/yyyy, use:

```
<input type="image" src="/Content/Images/calendar.png" id="DOB" name="DOB" value='<%=String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", Model.myTable.DOB)%>'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the datepicker class, and set up default value to the correct

```
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
```

and value you format as:

```
Model.myTable.DOB.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

and if you provide new value for the element use following

```
<%: Html.Helper("yourfield", new {ID="datepicker", @Value="your newValue"})  %>
```

good luck